# Ember: How to rewrite/extend RESTAdapter to make it site wide?

Tags: ajax, ember.js, cross-domain, ember-data, adapter

If I extend adapter in **app/adapters/application.js**

```
let appAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
    hash = hash || {};
    hash.crossDomain = true;
    hash.xhrFields = {
        withCredentials: true
    };
    return this._super(url, method, hash);
  },
});

export default appAdapter.reopen(config.adapterSettings);
```

it will still be superseded by model specific Adapters which I also have.

I have a few specific Adapters, for example: **app/adapters/testpost.js**

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(myTemplates, {
  myTemplate: `${host}/${dir}/testpost`,
});
```

For now to make it work, I extended each of them with the same piece of code, for example  **app/adapters/testpost.js** became:

```
let testpostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
    hash = hash || {};
    hash.crossDomain = true;
    hash.xhrFields = { 
        withCredentials: true
    };
    return this._super(url, method, hash);
  },
});

export default testpostAdapter.extend(myTemplates, {
  myTemplate: `${host}/${dir}/testpost`,
});
```

***The question:*** 
How to extend/rewrite RESTAdapter for all Ember, and for all specific adapters at once.

Tried to extend in **app/app.js**, doesn't work that way.

Comment: Extending the application adapter should work? Have you tried to `import ApplicationAdapter from './application';` in `adapters/testpost.js` and extend it `export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({})`

Comment: Thank you, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should not* directly derive from `DS.RESTAdapter.` in a model specific adapter, rather derive from your application adapter. So replace this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({...})
```

in your model specific adapters with this:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application'; // assuming not in pod structure
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({...});
```